# Как можно определить последний символ в файле?

Tags: c, файлы

У меня есть бинарный файл неизвестного размера. В нем находится текст в бинарном виде, зашифрованный по алгоритму [LZW](https://habr.com/ru/post/132683/)

Для теста я взял строку `abacabadabacabae` как в примере выше. После сжатия я получил такой файл с бинарным кодом

```
  6100 0000 6200 0000 6100 0000 6300 0000
  0001 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000 0401 0000
  0301 0000 0101 0000
```

Как видно последний код — `0101 0000` или `101` (`e`). Поэтому можно сделать вывод, что сжатие текста правильное. Моя процедура декомпрессии по алгоритму возвращает мне строку `abacabadabacababa` вместо `abacabadabacabae`, то есть почему-то не считывает последний код.

Я попробовал отследить последний символ в файле вручную внутри цикла декомпрессии, но это не помогло. Вот мое условие:

```
while (!feof(inFile)){
    if (feof(inFile)-ftell(inFile)==1){
        fread(&codeInFile, sizeof(int), 1, inFile);
        fprintf(outFile, "%s", codeInFile);
        break;
     }
        ...
 }
```

Есть еще вариант, но это условие тоже не отрабатывает

```
fseek(inFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
long fileSize = ftell(inFile);
rewind(inFile);
while (!feof(inFile)){
if (ftell(inFile)== (fileSize-1)){
        fread(&codeInFile, sizeof(int), 1, inFile);
        printf("%s", codeInFile);
        break;
        }

}
```

Как еще можно отследить последний символ в файле?

Comment: Что-то непонятно, что вы вообще этим хотите добиться- `if (feof(inFile)-ftell(inFile)==1)`?..

Comment: @Harry Если положение конца файла - текущее положение указателя в файле = 1, то это последний символ в файле. Так ведь?

Comment: `feof(inFile)` - это 0, если последнее чтение было успешно, и *не ноль*, если последнее чтение было неудачным из-за выхода за конец файла. И все.

Comment: @Harry Тогда у меня есть еще код, который тоже не сработал. Сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: Объясните, что вы хотите. Вы хотите читать поочередно все символы, и в какой-то момент получить, что это - последний? или вам просто нужно знать значение последнего байта в файле? Кстати, цикл `while (!feof(inFile)){` не работает - потому что признак конца файла, как я только что вам писал, устанавливается **после неудачного чтения**...

Comment: @Harry Я хочу 1) читать все коды символов поочередно (делаю это в while) 2) узнать, нахожусь ли я на последнем коде перед EOF 2.1) Если да, то прочесть этот код и вывести в  выходной файл символ с этим кодом 2,2) прервать цикл. Со 2 и 2.1 пунктами у меня проблемы

Comment: @Harry цикл while отработает. Я читаю коды в файле с помощью fread(). Просто не стал показывать это, ведь это не относится к теме вопроса.

Comment: Цикл сделает одно лишнее чтение, если вы не будете проверчять результат `fread`. Глупый вопрос - как открыт файл? Как бинарный?

Comment: @Harry Да файл открыт в режиме rb

Comment: @Harry странно получилось... проверил fread — вышел из цикла. от лишней ba избавился. За циклом переместил указатель в файле на (размер файла - 1 int) прочел код с помощью fread () и мне выдало код слова ba... хотя в файле явно записан код 101...

Comment: Вы читаете именно int'ами? У вас размер файла точно кратен 4? :)

Comment: @Harry читаю int-ами, размер файла 40 байт

Comment: Ну, гляньте в код в ответе. Но почему вы, читая `int`ы, говорите о последнем "символе"?...

Comment: @Harry я пытался расшифровать файл. В файле находятся int-ы коды символов изначальной строки. Последний код по алгоритму совпадает с кодом какой-то буквы в ASCII-таблице..

Comment: Ну, ваше дело... Как отследить последний `int`, я вам написал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему. Спасибо [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) за наводку в комментариях. Проблема была в функции сжатия. Чтоб записать код последнего символа в файл я прописал в функции сжатия:

```
int stop;
while (!feof(inFile)){

    if (stop = fread(&currentCharCode, 1, 1, inFile) !=1){
        fwrite(&currentCharCode, sizeof(int), 1, outFile);
        break;
    }
 ...
 }
```

А в функции распаковки

```
int stop;
    while (!feof(inFile)){
    stop = fread(&codeInFile, sizeof(int), 1, inFile);
    if (stop != 1) break;
    ...
    }
```

То есть, если fread вернула не количество успешно считанных объектов, а что-то другое, то был достигнут конец файла и в первом аргументе `fread()`находится последний блок памяти, который нам нужен. В сжатии — один последний байт, в процедуре разжатия — 4 байта.

Answer (score 1):

Просто чтоб показать вариант чтения:

```
FILE * f = fopen("data","rb");
fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(f);
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
printf("size of file - %d bytes\n",sz);
for(int i, pos = 0; fread(&i,sizeof(i),1,f) == 1; pos+=4)
{
    if (pos == sz-4) puts("Last int: ");
    printf("At pos %3d : 0x%08X\n", pos, i);
}
fclose(f);
```

Этот код у меня честно читал из 40-байтного файла 10 int'ов. Посмотрите, может, чем поможет...